# Where should Rails 3 custom validators be stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, customvalidator

I've seen docs/websites show that custom validators should go in a `/lib` or `/lib/validators` directory of a project. I've found (by reading an answer to another post) that they only seem to work in `config/initializers`. Does anyone know, or have a pointer to official documentation that shows where custom validators should live?

Comment: How about [changing the accepted answer flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263239/where-should-rails-3-custom-validators-be-stored/6610270#comment16660135_6610270)?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

If you place your custom validators in `app/validators` they will be automatically loaded without needing to alter your `config/application.rb` file.

Comment: I don't know if there's some gem/config you need to add for this, but under rails 3.2.8 this doesn't work. Specifically, simply dropping your validator into app/validators/???.rb doesn't work.

Comment: Doug try to name the validator file same way the validator class is named but underscored: MyCoolValidator goes to app/validators/my_cool_validator.rb

Comment: @Doug you need to restart your server. The autoload paths are expanded on initialization so new subfolders will not get picked up until you do that.

Comment: I like to also monkeypatch ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods to add a helper for my new validation (e.g. validates_address for AddressValidator).  When I include both the monkeypatch and the Validator in app/validators/address_validator.rb only the AddressValidator object is loaded, not the monkeypatch.  Are you guys experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: `spring stop` was necessary for me in Rails 5.2, otherwise it wasn't picked up.

Answer (score 15):

If you add this to your /config/application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/lib/validators/"]
```

Then Rails will automatically load your validators on start up (just like /config/initializers/), but you keep the clean structure of having your validators in one nice, well named spot.

Comment: Good idea but your code needs some cleanup:  
`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/validators/)`

Answer (score 6):

`lib/validators` seems by far the cleanest. However you may need to load them in before your models, so probably from an initializer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) about custom validations. AFAIK its a good practice to keep them in the relevant models.

Comment: Unless they're applicable to multiple models, in which case you should keep them elsewhere to stay DRY.

Comment: Which is what they presumably are because otherwise there's little point in creating a separate class for them.

Comment: @Jakub Yes there is: Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: The link to the official docs is broken. Here is the current location of that documentation; http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators