# Regex in ruby with AND operator

Tags: ruby, regex

I had a regex that detects when a string IS NOT the given pattern:

```
/\A((?!.*(www|http|@|\.com\b|\.net\b|\.de\b|\.info\b)).*)$/m
```

It means that strings like "hi you at www.test.com" is FALSE
But now I would liket to allow one URL: www.example.com.

It means:

" this is a test" > TRUE

"this is a test **www.example.com**" > TRUE

"this is a test **example.com** this" > TRUE

"this is a test **www.test.com** this" > FALSE

"this is a test **test.com** this" > FALSE

"this is a test **test.com** this **www.example.com** " > FALSE (false because one forbiden URL is present)

It seems I need to include an AND operator, I think it is:

```
(?=.*PATTERN)
```

but unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

ps: I know that this regex that detects urls is not perfect at all, but because my requirements it is bettern than nothing.

Thanks !

Edit:
My regex is located in a validator:

```
def self.validates_is_url_and_email_free(*attr_name)
    validates_format_of attr_name, {:with => /\A((?!.*(www|http|@|\.com\b|\.net\b|\.de\b|\.info\b)).*)$/m, :message => I18n.t(:not_url_email)}
end
```

Comment: What are you doing with this match? Why not extract the URI and then do a secondary operation on it? `gsub` and `scan` might help. It seems odd you're using a negative assertion `?!` when you want a positive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good way to validate links (urls) in rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails-3) -- there are some good ideas there that don't involve rails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case using two separate expressions might be the solution:

```
OKAY_EXPR = /example\.com/
BANNED_EXPR = /.../ # Existing expression

if (string.match(OKAY_EXPR) and !string.match(BANNED_EXPR))
  # ...
end
```

It's not clear what you're doing here, but that does seem to be an extremely restrictive set of TLDs. There are literally thousands of [valid TLDs](http://publicsuffix.org/list/) which might need to be processed.

Comment: I have added more details in edit section, I don't know how put your code in my :with, if it is possible.
thanks !

Comment: That's a Rails 2.x style validation. Rails 3 has a new syntax: `validates ..., :format => { :with => /.../ }` to do this. In any case, you can always write your own validation routine that does whatever you want and avoid having to write a very complicated regular expression that does it all in one shot. It is possible to express it with some tricky look-ahead negative assertions, but it would end up being almost unreadable line-noise.

Comment: Yes, I'm using rails 2. Could you show me an example how white this validation routine ?

Comment: `validate :method_name` will trigger a call to `method_name` during the validations. Your method can then do whatever tests it needs, inject any errors using `errors.add`, and if there's a failure, return `false` to stop the save chain. More examples in [the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate).