# Replace all URL unless it is allowed

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I had a regex that replaced all URLs from a given string:

```
my_string = "www.example.com test www.mysite.com"
my_string.gsub!(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|net|de|org|uk|biz|info|co.uk|es|de)(\/\S*)?/i,'(site hidden)')
```

As a result of the above I get: **"(site hidden) test (site hidden)"**

How could I change the regex to not replace www.mysite.com ???

It means that the replace should output **"(site hidden) test www.mysite.com"**

Thanks !

Comment: How about `(?! ..)` (no-match group)?

Comment: I see your regex [has grown since last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444811/regex-in-ruby-with-and-operator). Is this some kind of ad-hoc list you're creating here, or is the intention to be more thorough?

Comment: @tadman, this is ad-hoc, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about bruteforce? :)

```
my_string = "www.example.com test www.mysite.com"

regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|net|de|org|uk|biz|info|co.uk|es|de)(\/\S*)?/i

uniq  = rand(2**1024).to_s

p my_string.gsub('mysite.com', uniq).gsub(regex, '(site hidden)').gsub(uniq, 'mysite.com')
```

#### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=replace-all-url-unless-it-is-allowed.rb&run=true)

Comment: There should be a clever name for this pattern. I've had to do it before, often using something awful like `\0` to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a block to generate the replacement, using the original text if it's in the list of allowed entries:

```
my_string = "www.example.com test www.mysite.com"
allowed = %w(www.mysite.com)
re = %r/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|net|de|org|uk|biz|info|co.uk|es|de)(\/\S*)?/i
my_string.gsub!(re) do
  |m| allowed.include?(m) ? m : '(site hidden)'
end
puts my_string
```

Comment: `gsub` plus a block are powerful allies. This would be even better if `allowed` was a hash to avoid geometric increase of substitution times as the list grows. `hash = Hash[array.collect{|v|[v,true]}]` is a quick way to convert it.

Comment: @tadman Using a Hash would indeed be a good idea if there's to be a large list of fixed strings to allow.  But I suspect a real implementation would need to have one or more regexps to allow large sets of URLs.