# How to validate the format of a website url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, uri

I know this has been asked a few times but I still can't get it to work.

In my model I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'uri'
  attr_accessible :website
  validates :website, presence: true
end
```

All I want to do is check if its a valid formatted web address.

When I enter the lines of code below in console they both return true

```
!!URI.parse('www.fake.com')
```

and

```
!!URI.parse('fake')
```

How would I incorporate Simone's answer ([A good way to validate urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails-3)) into my model to validate the format of the web address?

```
def valid?(uri)
  !!URI.parse(uri)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'uri'
  attr_accessible :website
  validates :website, presence: true
  validate :website_url_format_valid?

  private

  def website_url_format_valid?
     uri = URI.parse(url)
     uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
   rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      false
    end
end
```

Comment: That's what I've tried. My only change was uri = URI.parse(self.website). I did a puts of uri and got www.address.com and I did another puts for uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) and get false. Any ideas?

Comment: In console I run uri = URI.parse('www.google.com') and get => #<URI::Generic:0x007fb7ce982ca8 URL:www.google.com> then I run uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) and get => false

Comment: the kind_of clause is trying to make sure you enter http://www.google.com rather than just www.google.com

Comment: I need to accept www as well as many other types of web site addresses. How do I get around this?