# How to validate a url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there an easy way how to validate urls in Rails 4 without using a Gem?

I found the validate_url gem already but i dont actually want to use it, as I think there needs to be a built-in way of doing that

Comment: Same question is already answered [What's a good way to validate links (urls) in rails 3?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails-3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a good way to do validate an url in rails 4 with a method of the URI class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
end
```

Comment: and it's match even `http:`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Mik's answer, I also use the browser HTML form:

```
<%= f.url_field :url %>
```