# Safely storing html rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I have a rails 4 app where I am storing urls in a database. When rails escapes it, the link is no longer usable when I try to call it again.

So I use:

```
<%= @product.url.html_safe %>
```

But isn't vulnerable to XSS? I read up on raw() as well but it seems to the do the same thing as html_safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use `URI.parse` to ensure the URL is being escaped:

```
<%= URI.parse @product.url %>
```

However, this is best placed inside a validation:

[Rails: What's a good way to validate links (URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would add validation on url to ensure it is valid url:

```
class Product < AR::Base
  validate :valid_url

  private

  def valid_url
    return if url.blank? || !url_changed
    URI.parse url
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    errors.add :url, :invalid
  end
end
```

With this in place you can be sure there are no XSS possibilities.