# How to validate url in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, url

I have Url model have url column and I want to validate that column to be a valid url, I have try with this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :url, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https))
end
```

But when I enter this url: `http://ruby3arabi` it's accept it, any ideas?

Comment: This problem was deeply discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls-in-rails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: What's a good way to validate links (URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/rails-whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem with this gem https://github.com/ralovets/valid_url

Comment: This gem is widely out of date in 2020, it will fail with several valid TLDs

Answer (score 14):

I tested and found that **URI::regexp(%w(http https))** or **URI::regexp** are not good enough.

The troubleshooting is using this regular expression

```
/\A(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?\z/ix
```

Option:

- i - case insensitive
- x - ignore whitespace in regex
- \A - start of regex (safely uses `\A` for Rails compares to `^` in common case)
- \z - end of regex (safely uses `\z` for Rails compares to `$` in common case)

So if you want to validate in model, you should use this instead:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  URL_REGEXP = /\A(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?\z/ix
  validates :url, format: { with: URL_REGEXP, message: 'You provided invalid URL' }
end
```

Test:

- [1] ***URI::regexp(%w(http https))***

  Test with wrong urls:

  - http://ruby3arabi - result is invalid
  - http://http://ruby3arabi.com - result is invalid
  - http:// - result is invalid

Test with correct urls:

- http://ruby3arabi.com - result is invalid
- http://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is invalid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is invalid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1) - result is invalid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en) - result is invalid
- ***[2] URI::regexp***

  Test with wrong urls:

  - http://ruby3arabi - result is valid
  - http://http://ruby3arabi.com - result is valid
  - http:// - result is valid

Test with correct urls:

- http://ruby3arabi.com - result is valid
- http://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en) - result is valid
- ***[3] /^(http|https)://[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$/ix***

  Test with wrong urls:

  - http://ruby3arabi - result is invalid
  - http://http://ruby3arabi.com - result is invalid
  - http:// - result is invalid

Test with correct urls:

- http://ruby3arabi.com - result is valid
- http://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com](http://www.ruby3arabi.com) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/article/1) - result is valid
- https://[www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en](http://www.ruby3arabi.com/websites/58e212ff6d275e4bf9000000?locale=en) - result is valid

Credit: Thanks [noman tayyab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3592881/noman-tayyab), ref:[Active Record Validations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) for update in case `\A` and  `\z`

Comment: I would say this is the perfect regex I've been looking for.

Comment: Above Regex throws an argument error (a security concern of multiline expressions) in rails 4. The alternate is to use \A for start of string and \z for end.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using URI.parse: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse

Comment: Can you explain how to use this with Rails? thank you

Comment: There is very good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/rails-whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls