# Can't save a certain string to a Postgresql db using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, save

I've got a rails model that accepts a title and a url that are both strings to allow users to put a link to an article on their profile page.  I've got a certain link that won't save and I'm not sure why.

Here is the link: https://khabar.ndtv.com/news/bollywood/katrina-kaif-sidharth-malhotra-aditya-roy-kapur-prepping-or-avengers-viral-video-1845153?pfrom=home-bollywood

My model is named CompanyProfileNewsLink and here is what I'm doing in the console to test:

```
n = CompanyProfileNewsLink.new
n.id = 1
n.title = "Indian article"
n.url = "https://khabar.ndtv.com/news/bollywood/katrina-kaif-sidharth-malhotra-aditya-roy-kapur-prepping-or-avengers-viral-video-1845153?pfrom=home-bollywood"
n.company_id = 1
n.save
```

It responds with:

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
```

and it hangs up there and never responds with COMMIT.  I've tried various variations of that url and all of them save fine.  If I remove the ? and the = from the link, it will save, but with either of those in the string, it won't save.  Now, I can update an existing record and put that url in and it updates fine.  Any ideas?  It's strange.

I'm using a gem named MetaInspector and it grabs the metadata from a link. 
 Here is the model:

```
class CompanyProfileNewsLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  before_validation :smart_add_url_protocol
  validates_presence_of :title, :url
  validates_format_of :url, :with => /\A(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?\Z/i, :on => :create
  validate :check_link

protected

  def smart_add_url_protocol
    unless self.url[/\Ahttp:\/\//] || self.url[/\Ahttps:\/\//]
      self.url = "http://#{self.url}"
    end
  end

  def check_link
    begin
      news_link = MetaInspector.new(url, :connection_timeout => 12, :read_timeout => 7, :retries => 3)
    rescue MetaInspector::RequestError, MetaInspector::ParserError
      errors.add(:url, "#{url} is either not available or not correct.")
    rescue MetaInspector::TimeoutError
      errors.add(:url, "#{url}) has timed out.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the model please

Comment: This `n.id = 1` is bad idea. Leave setting `id` to the database itself.

Comment: Yes, I should've left the id up to the database. Thanks. I've added the model to the original post. I would think if it was a problem with the regex that it would give me an error rather than just not saving. I'm still quite new to all this. Thanks for looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was an issue with the regex I was using that wasn't allowing that url to go through.  I ended up using a solution something like the one in this other question instead: [Rails: What's a good way to validate links (URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167895/rails-whats-a-good-way-to-validate-links-urls)

Comment: I don't think that was the issue. That doesn't explain why your server hangs up on saving a record.

Comment: Yeah, if it didn't work with the regex, shouldn't it return an error?

Comment: Yes, if the email was invalid as per the regex, it should have returned an error on object.