# Rails 3, Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, email

I try to add an email-validator in my rails app. I created the following file `/lib/validators/email_validator.rb`

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i  
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly")  
    end  
  end  
end
```

In the application.rb I added this line:

`config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib/validators"`

And here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password,:name
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :email => true  
end
```

If i want to start the server I got an error:

```
Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator' (ArgumentError)
```

Has anybody an idea how I can fix this problem?

Comment: How to use this with rails 5. it will not validate email using `ActiveModel::EachValidator`. EmailValidator class is not invoke.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If you place your custom validators in app/validators they will be
>   automatically loaded without needing to alter your
>   config/application.rb file.

Resource: [Where should Rails 3 custom validators be stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263239/where-should-rails-3-custom-validators-be-stored) (second answer)

Answer (score 6):

This error occures, because rails loads model file before your validation file

Try to require your validation file manually at the start of your model file

```
require_dependency 'validators/email_validator.rb'
```

Comment: This was the only way I could fix this in a Rails 6.1 app, adding it to the autoload paths would not work.

Answer (score -3):

Try the modified User model;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :password,:name

  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

end
```

Comment: This is not problem solution