# Rails custom validator not working in console only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a custom validator `dimensions_validator` in app/validators.

Works fine in the app in development. But when I bring up the `rails console` and try to load that model, `PngPic.count`, I get `ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'DimensionsValidator'`. What gives? How is the console different than the WEBrick server?

I've restarted the console a few times, no luck.

Comment: Is your `validators` folder in autoload paths?

Comment: @Broi Pretty sure, since the validator is actually working on localhost:3000. Haven't specifically added it, as apparently the app/validators folder is automatically added.

Comment: Might be that your server loaded it before (maybe there is a require in some other model) so it is not raising anything but the console has no idea where it is. Try adding it in application.rb and restart the console.

Comment: That worked, had to explicitly add it, which is going against what I'd read. `config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]`. Feel free to add that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out this threads and compare with your own.

[Rails 3, Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282628/rails-3-unknown-validator-emailvalidator)

[Where should Rails 3 custom validators be stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263239/where-should-rails-3-custom-validators-be-stored)