# How can I load a custom validator which does not directly inherit from a Rails validator class in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, customvalidator

I was writing some custom validators for a Rails 5 project I have been working on. For example:

```rb
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.present? && !/\A[^\p{Z}]+@[^\p{Z}]+\.[^\p{Z}]+\z/.match?(value)
      record.errors.add(attribute, "must be an email")
    end
  end
end
```

This approach worked fine, but many of my custom validators were similarly checking for a regex match so I decided to create an abstract `RegexValidator` class:

```rb
class RegexValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  self.abstract_class = true

  def regex
    raise "Children of this class must implement the 'regex' method."
  end

  def message(record, attribute, value)
    raise "Children of this class must implement the 'message(record, attribute, value)' method."
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.present? && !regex.match?(value)
      record.errors.add(attribute, message(record, attribute, value))
    end
  end
end
```

So now `EmailValidator` is implemented like so:

```rb
class EmailValidator < RegexValidator
  def regex
    /\A[^\p{Z}]+@[^\p{Z}]+\.[^\p{Z}]+\z/
  end

  def message(record, attribute, value)
    "must be an email"
  end
end
```

However, since this change Rails 5 no longer autoloads my `EmailValidator` even though both `RegexValidator` and `EmailValidator` are placed in appropriately named files, `regex_validator.rb` and `email_validator.rb`, in the `app/validators` folder which was being autoloaded before (this makes this question different from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282628)). I suspect this is because `EmailValidator` no longer directly inherits from `ActiveModel::EachValidator`, but this should not matter.

For reference, the following error occurred when I tried to generate a migration file:

```rb
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:121:in `rescue in block in validates': Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator' (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:118:in `block in validates'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:114:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.2/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:114:in `validates'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/app/models/user.rb:7:in `<class:User>'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/app/models/user.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:476:in `block in load_file'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:661:in `new_constants_in'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:475:in `load_file'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:373:in `block in require_or_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `block in load_missing_constant'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:57:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:316:in `get'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise.rb:346:in `add_mapping'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.5.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/config/routes.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:879:in `scope'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'                                                      
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        from /home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My `User` class:

```rb
##
# A class representing a user account for this web application
# Instances of this class represent rows in the +users+ table on the database.
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Validation
  validates_presence_of :email, :encrypted_password
  validates :email, email: true

  # Associations
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  # Events
  before_validation do
    # Removes unnecessary whitespace
    self.email = email.strip
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide User model code for line 4 to 7 ?

Comment: Okay, I add the `User` class code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3, Unknown validator: 'EmailValidator'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15282628/10522579)

Comment: take a look, https://stackoverflow.com/q/15282628/10522579

Comment: I did, the fix for that question was to place the validators in `app/validators`, but that's already where my classes are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The `self.abstract_class = true` line in `RegexValidator` was silently raising an error because there is no `self.abstract_class` method in the class. I thought there was because I saw it in the `ApplicationRecord` class, but I now realize that this is defined in the `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

I determined this by adding `require_relative "../validators/email_validator"` to the top of the `user.rb` file. After doing that I was able to see the error which was silent before:

```
/home/tomeraberbach/Desktop/msf/src/app/validators/regex_validator.rb:4:in `<class:RegexValidator>': undefined method `abstract_class=' for RegexValidator:Class (NoMethodError)
```

After removing the `self.abstract_class = true` line and the `require_relative "../validators/email_validator"` line, the problem was resolved.