# Rails 4: undefined method `facebook_copy_link' for LinkValidator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

In my Rails 4, I have a `Post` model I need to implement a custom validation on.

Following the recommendation [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263239/where-should-rails-3-custom-validators-be-stored) and [in the documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators), I have implemented the following code:

```
#app/validators/link_validator.rb

class LinkValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.format == "Link"
      unless facebook_copy_link(record.copy)
        record.errors[:copy] << 'Please make sure the copy of this post includes a link.'
      end
    end
  end
end

#post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with LinkValidator
  [...]
end
```

—————

**UPDATE**: The `facebook_copy_link` method is defined as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  [...]
  def facebook_copy_link(string)
    require "uri"
    array = URI.extract(string.to_s)
    array.select { |item| item.include? ( "http" || "www") }.first
  end
  [...]
end
```

—————

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
NameError at /posts/74/edit
uninitialized constant Post::LinkValidator
validates_with LinkValidator
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

—————

**UPDATE 2**: I had forgotten to restart the server.

Now, I get a new error:

```
NoMethodError at /posts/74
undefined method `facebook_copy_link' for #<LinkValidator:0x007fdbc717ba60 @options={}>
unless facebook_copy_link(record.copy)
```

Is there a way to include this method in the validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from being a Rails validator class, `LinkValidator` is also a Ruby class. So you can define pretty much any method on it.

The `facebook_copy_link` doesn't seem to be using the controller instance's state, so you could just easily move the method into the validator class:

```
require "uri"

class LinkValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.format == "Link"
      unless facebook_copy_link(record.copy)
        record.errors[:copy] << 'Please make sure the copy of this post includes a link.'
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def facebook_copy_link(string)
    array = URI.extract(string.to_s)
    array.select { |item| item.include? ( "http" || "www") }.first
  end
end
```

Note how I made the `facebook_copy_link` method private. This is simply good practice, as the only method being accessed by other objects is `validate`.

As a sidenote, it's not necessary to put `include ActiveModel::Validations` in an ActiveRecord subclass. Validations are already available in ActiveRecord classes.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful answer. Two quick questions if you don't mind: 1. the `facebook_copy_link` is actually used twice in the PostsController, which is the reason why it is currently located in the ApplicationController: given this new piece of information, would you still recommend to move it to  the validator class? 2. I see that you placed the `require "uri"` code before `class LinkValidator < ActiveModel::Validator`: is there a reason for that?

Comment: You *could* move the method into the model, but then every model requiring that validation has to define the method. Another option is to move it into a class other than the validator and the controller. As for the `require`, I prefer to have all dependencies listed at the top of a source file for clarity. :)